# ros kinetic nao simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, nao-robot, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone
i am a newbie in robotics , is there any nao simulator that i can install in my machine , i am using ros kinetic on ubuntu 16.04,
i have done some searches before asking, it seems that there is a nao simulator for ros indigo, but i don't know if it is possible to install a nao simulator using my actual config

thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256993/ros-kinetic-nao-simulation/) by [2fik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29515/2fik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed there is a [ros package for simulating nao in gazebo](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_virtual/tree/master/nao_gazebo_plugin) that is available on indigo
Unfortunately it has not been release into jade or kinetic yet.  The Gazebo plugins have been updated to use the new Gazebo API but the resulting simulation is unstable. You can track the progress of the release in kinetic on [this Github issue](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_virtual/issues/19)

.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1